# How to protect music files?

Tags: android, audio, encryption

As the title says, I have 1000mb audio files in my app (which has a media player ability also). I don't need a 100% protection. All I need is that when user downloads these audio files from the web, only my app could be able to find on open these files and if a normal user shares these files they couldn't open it.

I know a dedicated user or hacker can easily access the main files, all I need is a simple primitive protection from a ordinary user.

What is the best way to do this? Any suggestions or examples would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just write the files to your app private directory.  Then it can't be accessed by any app other than your own, unless the user roots the device.  If you want more protection than that, you really need to describe what attack vectors you're worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store those audio in folder named '.nomedia' without quotes.
OR
Use custom file extentions and and save those files using [Serialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)
To save object to file you need serialization.
You can choose whatever file extension we like e.g. .car.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple encrypt the header of the file not entire file, Your app will decrypt that header before playing it. You only need to encrypt few bytes so there is no performance issue.